# Equivalent of executing MySql stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I have created the following MySql stored procedure which works perfectly fine:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE UpsertContactable(
    IN Email VARCHAR(254),
    IN ServerId INT(11),
    IN Contactable BOOLEAN,
    IN LastUpdate TIMESTAMP
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE cnt INT DEFAULT 0;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO cnt
    FROM Contactable
    WHERE Contactable.Email = Email
      AND Contactable.Server__ = ServerId;
    IF ( cnt > 0 ) THEN
        UPDATE Contactable
        SET Contactable.Contactable = Contactable,
            Contactable.Last_Update = LastUpdate
        WHERE Contactable.Email = Email
          AND Contactable.Server__ = ServerId
          AND Contactable.Last_Update < LastUpdate;
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO Contactable (`Email`, `Server__`, `Contactable`, `Last_Update`)
        VALUES (Email, ServerId, Contactable, LastUpdate);

    END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Unfortunately, my company is against using stored procedure.

I know its possible to rewrite this (I am using PHP) with two calls to the database (i.e., one to compute `cnt`, the other to perform the `insert` or the `update`).

But considering the volume of data to process, I would like to avoid the extra round-trip to the database.

Is it possible to send a unique statement to the database per line to process and perform the same as the procedure, wihtout using this procedure?

Comment: May be `REPLACE INTO Contactable (Email, Server__, Contactable, Last_Update) VALUES (Email, ServerId, Contactable, LastUpdate);` make sance

Comment: @dima No, because I update iif `Contactable.Last_Update < LastUpdate;`

Comment: Can Contactable.Last_Update be greater then LastUpdate? I do not have enough information about logic of this task to find solutions.

Comment: Yes it can. That's why I am performing a check.